# xp_cmdshell proxy account disabled Automatically

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, database-administration, xp-cmdshell

when i want to execute `xp_cmdshell` sp is sql server
it give me error that I don't have permission to run `xp_cmdshell`.
when i check in security tab in Property window of instance,in the `service Proxy Account` section
`enable service account Proxy` check box is set.
after deselecting this check box and select it again and set user name and password,
I can execute xp_cmdshell.

My question is why this happen ...?what action can disable service account Proxy.
is a normal behavior what is your idea.
it happen recently and it happne multile time.

Comment: This should be asked on the DBA site; I've voted to move it. It isn't really clear what you're seeing, but if something is being reset then one possible reason would be a [schedule-based policy](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb510667(v=sql.100).aspx).

Answer (score 0):

Does this happen frequently or has it only happened the once?
It could be that some configuration changes did not take place initially.